# Xtext parsing rule uncomplete

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, xtext

I am using following excerpt in the grammar for my DSL:

```
SelectDml:
    'select' columnList+=FieldColumn (',' columns+=FieldColumn)* from=FromClause;

FromClause:
    'from' value=ID (alias=ID)?;

FieldColumn hidden():
    fieldName=ID ('.' ID)?;
```

If I parse following line of my DSL, then there is one FieldColumn in the column-List which is absolutely fine. But the FieldColumn has the fieldName `a` and not the expected value: `a.col`.

```
select a.col from a
```

Is there a problem with my grammar? Something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this rule

```
FieldColumn hidden():
      fieldName=ID ('.' ID)?;
```

the first `ID` value is assigned to `fieldName`. Any further `ID` values are just skipped.

Comment: Why are the further `ID` values skipped? How can I prevent this?

Comment: well the rule consumes multiple tokens, but only the first one is handled. Add some code to deal with the others.

Comment: I have added another Rule: `FieldColumnName: ID ('.' ID)?;` and assinged this to the `fieldName`. Thanks for your hint :)